# VIPER Architecture

Tags: design-patterns, swift, ios

I write Swift and architect apps mostly based on VIPER pattern. The thing I always wonder is, is it a proper to store some temporal values in `Interactor`? Let me show some examples I often write, excluding boilerplates like 'inits' nor 'injections':

**ex. 1: Object Validation (View -> Presenter -> Interactor -> DataStore)**

```
// Entity
struct Person: PersonEntity {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
}

// Interactor IO
class PersonAddDefaultInteractor: PersonAddInteractor {

    let dataSource: PersonAddDataStore
    weak var output: PersonAddInteractorOutput?

    var model: PersonEntity = Person(name: nil, age: nil) // <- IS THIS ACCEPTABLE APPROACH?

    func updateName(_ name: String) {
        model.name = name 
    }

    func updateAge(_ age: Int) {
        model.age = age 
    }

    func validate() {
        output?.validated(success: model.name != nil && model.age != nil)
    }

    func save() {
        dataSource.save(model)
    }
}

// Presenter
class PersonAddDefaultPresenter: PersonAddPresenter {

    weak var view: PersonAddView?
    let interactor: PersonAddInteractor
    let router: PersonAddWireframe

    func updateName(_ name: String) {
        interactor.updateName(name)
        interactor.validate()
    }

    func updateAge(_ age: Int) {
        interactor.updateAge(age)
        interactor.validate()
    }

    func save() {
        interactor.save()
    }
}

extension PersonAddDefaultPresenter: PersonAddInteractorOutput {

    func validated(success: Bool) {
        view?.setSaveButtonEnabled(success)

        if !success {
            router.showAlertController()
        }
    }
}

// View
class PersonAddViewController: UIViewController {

    var presenter: PersonPresenter?
    let saveButton: UIButton = UIButton()

    @objc func updateName(_ sender: UITextField) {
        guard let name: String = sender.text else { return }
        presenter?.updateName(name)
    }

    @objc func updateAge(_ sender: UISlider) {
        presenter?.updateAge(Int(sender.value))
    }

    @objc func save(_ sender: Any) {
        presenter?.save()
    }
}

extension PersonAddViewController: PersonView {

    func setSaveButtonEnabled(_ isEnabled: Bool) {
        saveButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
    }
}
```

The point here is, naturally you cannot obtain values that `UITextField` and `UISlider` has at the same time. (or must I make a func to do that?). Thus, I tend to - well, actually all the time - make temporal values/states/flags variables on `Interactor`, then do validate things using those stored values.

---

**ex. 2: Fetching DataSource asynchronously without closures (DataSource -> Interactor -> Presenter -> View -> UICollectionView)**

```
// Entity
struct Person: PersonEntity {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
}

// DataSource IO
class PersonDefaultDataSource: PersonDataSource {

    weak var output: PersonDataSourceOutput?

    func fetch() {
        output?.fetched([/* some data */])
    }
}

// Interactor IO
class PersonDefaultInteractor: PersonInteractor {

    let dataSource: PersonDataStore
    weak var output: PersonInteractorOutput?

    var models: [PersonEntity] = [] // <- IS THIS ACCEPTABLE APPROACH?

    func fetch() {
        dataSource.fetch()
    }

    func numberOfItems() -> {
        return models.count
    }

    func fetchItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> PersonEntity {
        return models[indexPath.row]
    }
}

class PersonDefaultInteractor: PersonDataSourceOutput {

    func fetched(_ models: [PersonEntity]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.models = models
            self.output?.fetchedItems()
        }
    }
}

// Presenter
class PersonDefaultPresenter: PersonPresenter {

    weak var view: PersonView?
    let interactor: PersonInteractor
    let router: PersonWireframe

    func onViewDidLoad() {
        interactor.fetch()
    }

    func numberOfItems() -> {
        return interactor.numberOfItems()
    }

    func fetchItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> PersonEntity {
        return interactor.fetchItem(at: indexPath)
    }
}

extension PersonDefaultPresenter: PersonInteractorOutput {

    func fetchedItems() {
        view?.reloadCollectionView()
    }
}

// View
class PersonAddViewController: UIViewController {

    var presenter: PersonPresenter?
    let collectionView = UICollectionView()

    override func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        presenter?.onViewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension PersonAddViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) {
        return presenter?.numberOfItems() ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue...etc
        let item = presenter?.fetchItem(at: indexPath)

        cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
        cell.ageLabel.text = item.age

        return cell
    }
}

extension PersonAddViewController: PersonView {

    func reloadCollectionView() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So, in this case, because I do want to avoid using dozens of closures:

1. I fetch some data from DataSource asynchronously and store them in `Interactor`
2. Then notify presenter that interactor obtained needed models
3. Presenter notify view, that datasource is ready and do `UICollectionView.reloadData()` for the first time

---

Do you have an idea what I am describing what I am doing now? Simply saying, when needed values to do a task are from individual controls, the solution only I can think of is to store each values on somewhere and keep those values latest. Or, would function like below - collecting values from all individual controls all the time when a value is needed - fit more in VIPER?

```
var nameTextField: UITextField!
var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

func collectCurrentValues() {
    presenter?.updateName(nameTextField.text!)
    presenter?.updateDescription(descriptionTextView.text!)
}
```

Comment: should this has been posted at stackoverflow...?